# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in laravel project

Tags: mysql, laravel, forms, model-view-controller, formbuilder

Hello I'm running a Laravel project and i got this error and i do not know from where, this is a part of code from my view where i created the form , it's only this because the inputs are repeating

```
  <div class="row"> 
        <p style="font-size: 14px;" class="ml-3 mt-1">2:</p>                        
           <div class="col-2 mb-1 pr-1 pl-1">
                                {{Form::text('gram2', '', ['class' => 'form-control category-style input-size input-size-evaluare p-1', 'id' => 'firstName']) }}
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                  Valid first name is required.
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-2 mb-1 pl-1 pr-1">
                              {{Form::select('karate2', null, ['class' => 'custom-select d-block select-size pr-0', 'style' => 'font-size: 12px; width: 100%;', 'id' => 'country']) }}
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-2 mb-1 pr-1 pl-1">
                                {{Form::text('pietre2', '', ['class' => 'form-control category-style input-size-evaluare p-1', 'id' => 'lastName']) }}
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                  Valid last name is required.
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-2 mb-1 pl-1 pr-1">
                                {{Form::text('aur_prelucrat2', '', ['class' => 'form-control category-style input-size-evaluare p-1', 'id' => 'lastName']) }}
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                  Valid last name is required.
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-2 mb-1 pl-1 pr-1">
                                {{Form::text('price_per_gram2', '', ['class' => 'form-control category-style input-size-evaluare p-1', 'id' => 'lastName']) }}
                                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                  Valid last name is required.
                                </div>
                              </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is causing the error:

```
{{ Form::select('karate2', null, ['class' => 'custom-select d-block select-size pr-0', 'style' => 'font-size: 12px; width: 100%;', 'id' => 'country']) }}
```

The 2nd argument to `Form::select` is an **array** of values it can use to create each `<option>`. You're passing it `null`, and you can do a `foreach()` on `null`

If you simply modify this to be an empty array, it should work:

```
{{ Form::select('karate2', [], [ ... ]) }}
```

Edit: You might still need the `null` for the default value, but I haven't used `Form::select()` in quite some time, so I'm not sure.

```
{{ Form::select('karate2', [], null, [ ... ]) }}
```

Comment: as i remember 3rd parameter is default selected, 4th is for extra attribute

Comment: @AlzafanChristian Yup, I believe you are correct too; added as an edit :)

Comment: Yes, that's correct, it's working now, thank's a lot man ! :)